# How to fill remaining height inside nested div?

Tags: html, css

I have three boxes with heights 20%, 50%, 30% (=100%) inside my div wrapper. Each of the three boxes are split in two divs with classes "title" and "remaining".

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="one">
     <div class="title">title one</div>
     <div class="remaining">remaining one</div>
   </div>

   <div class="two">
     <div class="title">title two</div>
     <div class="remaining">remaining two</div>
   </div>

   <div class="three">
     <div class="title">title three</div>
     <div class="remaining">remaining three</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height:600px;
  width:300px;
  background:white;
}

.one {
  height:20%;
  background: blue;
}

.two {
  height:50%;
  background:yellow;
}

.three {
  height:30%;
  background:red;
}

.title {
  height:30px;
  background:black;
}

.remaining {
  background:green;
  height:65%; 
}
```

Here is an illustration:

[image]

My problem is getting the class called "remaining" to take up the **exact** remaining height of the parent div. In my example I set it to 65% which is obviously not correct. I also tried:

```
.remaining {
    background:green;
    height: (100% - 30px);
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/symenw0f/).

Is there some way to solve this with css?

Comment: Use `calc(100% - 30px)`.

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I added a fiddle to check it. Look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `calc()` to calculate your height.

```
.remaining {
  background:green;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/symenw0f/4/).

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
}
.one {
  height: 20%;
  background: blue;
}
.two {
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.three {
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}
.title {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
.remaining {
  background: green;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="title">title one</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <div class="title">title two</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="title">title three</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining three</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @brinch
Also revert back your question. I think in SO you should remain your question in tack without the answer. I was warned by the moderator before about it.
Also glad to be at help.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I have manually reverted the question back.

Answer (score 1):

**Notes:**

- You can do this by using the **`calc()`** function as shown in the code below.
- Also remove that **`/*`** from your CSS in your fiddle as it invalidates the closing curly brace.

**Code:**

```
.remaining {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

- Since the height of the **`.title`** is **`30px`** you need **`.remaining`** to fill 100% of the parent's height minus the height of the title.

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/symenw0f/3/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
}
.one {
  height: 20%;
  background: blue;
}
.two {
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.three {
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}
.title {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
.remaining {
  background: green;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="title">title one</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <div class="title">title two</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="title">title three</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining three</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @brinch

Answer (score 1):

You can always use flexbox. Each children of `.wrapper` should be a flex container. Set the axis to column and then tell `.remaining` to "grow":

```
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.remaining {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daslaf/ko884r63/)

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.one {
  height: 20%;
  background: blue;
}
.two {
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.three {
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}
.title {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
.remaining {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item one">
    <div class="title">title one</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="title">title two</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="title">title three</div>
    <div class="remaining">remaining three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll have to use vendor prefixes though. For more information go [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)